# virtualizing physical IIS box into Hyper-V breaks API, Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a physical IIS server that works just fine but when I convert it into Hyper-V, it seems to break an API I use to activate serial numbers. It just doesn't seem to connect. Everything else still works however, it booted up fine with no issues, the rest of the IIS services work fine, the website works fine too.

The owner of the API assures there is no changes or anything he can do on his end. When I plug my physical box in again, it starts working again. I previously had a very similar issue when I accidentally changed the subnet from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.254.0, it started giving me the same errors but I've assure that the correct network settings are there this time.

I am not the developer of the application but I do own the server, the developer has been completely useless in providing any help diagnose the issue as well.

If it helps, I am running a cisco router, a sonicwall firewall, for diagnosing this issue I have them both fairly open between me and the API server. I also have another physical server which is a DC AD/DNS/DHCP.

Both physical servers are running Server 2012 R2. The hyper-v host is also running 2012 R2. If it also helps, I have IIS logs of both when the API communication fails and when it passes through although they don't seem to provide many details.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or at least a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

EDIT: Also worth noting, I converted the physical machine into VMware using VMware converter, then I used the StarWind converter to V2V the VMWare image into a hyper-v image.

Comment: Why do you do so complicated? ever tried disk2vhd?

Comment: You still need to hire a developer (the original or another experienced) to take a look at the code (or reverse engineer the details) in order to know what exactly is the cause of the error (your experience on the subnet change can be one of the causes but probably not enough). What you asked is a rather complicated task, so I don't think anyone can give you an answer without touching your machine first.

Comment: @djdomi yes i tried disk2vhd and did not have any luck getting to even boot properly as vhd or vhdx format. it was quicker for me to one click convert to vmdk then one click convert to hyperv. too much time spent in repairing boot sectors, removing drivers, etc..

Comment: @LexLi I have some experience in l.a.m.p development but not .net applications, however I could likely figure my way around it. if I can get the api and connection string details, would you say that performing my own 'connection test' be of any help in diagnosing or getting towards the right path?

Comment: An intermediate/advanced .NET developer should be able to review (or disassemble) the source code easily and then track down the error, so you must give it a try or hire someone with that expertise.

Comment: disk2vhd requires AFAIK to have bios used for, meaning a version 1 type of machine

Answer (score 1):

StarWind V2V Converter is your best friend!

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter